# vertical carousel with offset for iOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, icarousel

I would like to make vertical menu with offset which is calculated by position. Center row is more on right than others, like in picture. Also center row is marked as pressed. Can anyone suggest some sample how to achieve that? Now I am looking at iCarousel, but can't find how to make vertical carousel like this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your image displayed in question, it looks like you can use this custom tableview code. 
Where in did select row method you can write your own logical code.

[CustomCircularTableView](https://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/uitableview-tricks/)

Hope this will work for you.

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: It is really good sample, but I can't make it work properly for 240x79 cells. It flows around

Comment: Thanks for your example. It suggested me how to make such animation. I couldn't make animation by sinx (too lazy to calculate exact formula for my pictures), so made simple by x function. Now trying to make fade and change paint order

Comment: I am happy that it helps you out.

Comment: Post your code (which you used) as well along with your question.. So it be useful to others for future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the vertical property to true/YES; And you will probably need to set the carousel type to iCarouselTypeCustom. Then you can override the delegate methods:

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForTransformOption:(iCarouselTranformOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value;
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemAlphaForOffset:(CGFloat)offset;
```

For an example I suggest looking inside iCarousel.m itself and following the example of iCarouselTypeWheel type. This will get very close to the effect you want, but you will need to add the custom highlighting code. For that, I suggest implementing the carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated: method and updating the views there (setting background color etc.).

Comment: can u make sample code? I find it difficult to make translations to achieve what I want